# How to implement Facebook drag and drop feature in uploading files

Tags: javascript, .net, facebook, drag-and-drop

Facebook has this feature where we can drag an image and then we can drag drop and reorder the image.

How to do so?

How to achieve that?

Is that a library for that kind of control on the web? Should we code the javascript ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drag and drop file uploading I've used https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload in the past. It is complicated but works well.

For dragging and dropping to reorder elements you can either try to implement it yourself or use something like http://jqueryui.com/sortable/.

Comment: great answer for a great question. And I wonder what the downvote. +1. Thanks for start.